# How to find all integer $x$ such that $x^{2}+5145x+2332\equiv 0\pmod{ 9797}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How to find all integer $x$ such that $x^{2}+5145x+2332\equiv 0\pmod{ 9797}$. I think $9797$ can factor, then $9797=97\cdot11$. So I can convert to $$x^{2}+5145x+2332\equiv 0\pmod{97}$$
$$x^{2}+5145x+2332\equiv 0\pmod{11}$$
How do to next? Thanks.

Comment: $9797=97\times 101$.

Comment: It's $x^2+4x+4\equiv0\bmod97$ and $x^2-6x+9\equiv0\bmod101$.  Do you know the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: @JWTanner why do I see the misspelling "proove" so often?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel:  perhaps people get confused because proof has two **o**s

Comment: You can ese the same CRT-based method as in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 1):

The coefficients may be factored as follows:
$$x^2+(15×7^3)x+(44×53)\equiv0\bmod(97×101)$$
Modulo $97$, the equation becomes
$$x^2+4x+4\equiv(x+2)^2\equiv0\bmod97$$
Modulo $101$,
$$x^2-6x+9\equiv(x-3)^2\equiv0\bmod101$$
(We have used the smallest absolute value possible for calculations to simplify the work.) Thus $x\equiv-2\bmod97\equiv3\bmod101$, or by the Chinese remainder theorem $x\equiv2326\bmod9797$.